# Writing std::string with non-ascii data to file

Tags: c++, string, utf-8, non-ascii-characters, utf

Below is a simplified example of my problem. I have some external byte data which appears to be a string with cp1252 encoded degree symbol `0xb0`. When it is stored in my program as an `std::string` it is correctly represented as `0xffffffb0`. However, when that string is then written to a file, the resulting file is only one byte long with just `0xb0`. How do I write the string to the file? How does the concept of `UTF-8` come into this?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

typedef struct
{
  char n[40];
} mystruct;

static void dump(const std::string& name)
{
  std::cout << "It is '" << name << "'" << std::endl;
  const char *p = name.data();
  for (size_t i=0; i<name.size(); i++)
  {
    printf("0x%02x ", p[i]);
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  const unsigned char raw_bytes[] = { 0xb0, 0x00};
  mystruct foo;
  foo = *(mystruct *)raw_bytes;
  std::string name = std::string(foo.n);
  dump(name);

  std::ofstream my_out("/tmp/out.bin", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
  my_out << name;
  my_out.close();

  return 0;
}
```

Running the above program produces the following on STDOUT

```sh
It is '�'
0xffffffb0
```

Comment: What do you expect if the actual byte is 0xb0? Forget ansi strings and use unicode anyway inside app, for serialization use UTF-8.

Comment: `std::string name = std::string(foo.n);` -- This does not construct a string containing two characters.

Comment: BTW, in C++ you don't need the `typedef` for `struct`.

Comment: 1. `*(mystruct *)raw_bytes` is not legal, anything could happen.  2. `0xffffffb0` is `0xb0` `char` value cast to `int`. It has nothing to do with ASCII, cp1252 or anything of this nature.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis - can you please clarify how I would go about converting external data which contains non-ascii byte 0xb0 into a unicode string?

Comment: There are libraries for, e. g. [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this is a must read:

[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Now, when you done with that, you have to understand what type represents `p[i]`.

It is `char`, which in C is a small size integer value with a `sign`! `char` can be negative!

Now, since you have `cp1252` characters, they are outside the scope of ASCII. This means these characters are seen as negative values!

Now, when they are converted to `int`, the sign bit is replicated, and when you are trying to print it, you will see `0xffffff<actual byte value>`.

To handle that in `C`, first you should cast to `unsigned char`:

```
printf("0x%02x ", (unsigned char)p[i]);
```

then the default conversion will fill in the missing bits with zeros and `printf()` will give you a proper value.

Now, in C++ this is a bit more nasty, since `char` and `unsigned char` are treated by stream operators as a character representation. So to print them in hex manner, it should be like this:

```
int charToInt(char ch) 
{
    return static_cast<int>(static_cast<unsigned char>(ch));
}

std::cout << std::hex << charToInt(s[i]);
```

Now, direct conversion from `char` to `unsigned int` will not fix the problem since silently the compiler will perform a conversation to `int` first.

See here: https://wandbox.org/permlink/sRmh8hZd78Oar7nF

UTF-8 has nothing to this issue.

Off-topic: please, when you write pure C++ code, do not use `C`. It is pointless and makes code harder to maintain, and it is not faster. So:

- do not use `char*` or `char[]` to store strings. Just use `std::string`.
- do not use `printf()`, use `std::cout` (or the `fmt` library, if you like format strings - it will became a future C++ standard).
- do not use `alloc()`, `malloc()`, `free()` - in modern C++, use `std::make_unique()` and `std::make_shared()`.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, as it was phrased. I guess I should have rephrased the questions. I have read Joe's article before and re-read it again right now. What I ultimately want to achieve is to take external data and covert it from what appears to be cp1252 encoding into UTF-8. There must be a c++ generic way to do that, but I cannot find it

Comment: I found the solution that works for me. In my original code, instead of `std::string name = std::string(foo.n);` I am now doing `std::string name = boost::locale::conv::to_utf<char>(foo.n, "Latin1");`